# find | grep doesn't search subfolders with spaces in names

Tags: bash, grep, find, xargs

```
find . -iname *.xml -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Eo ‘.{0,40}Peter.{0,40}’
```

This command works very well search subdirectories for my search string, but can't see folders with spaces in their names, and returns no results from them. I've added `-print0` to find and `-0` to `xargs` as recommended. The FILES with spaces in their names are being searched; it's the *recursion* that isn't working. I'd appreciate any thoughts on how to make the recursion work here with files with spaces in their names. And I would like to take a moment for a PSR about the tragedy of placing spaces in filenames. The more you know. Thank you.

Comment: you shouldn't specify `*.xml` after `grep`, the arguments (paths as found by `find`) are appended by `xargs` itself...

Comment: you're correct. this was one of many versions of the command I tested. I'll remove that parameter for clarity.

Comment: Replace the "smart quotes" (`‘` and `’`) with single quotes (`'`). There's no reason that find command should not search directories with spaces in their names though. What makes you think it doesn't? Please [edit] your question to make it clear if you're talking about directories or files with spaces being  the issue as you say both at different times. Also - folders is a Windows term, in UNIX it's either directories or files.

Comment: Thanks Ed, directories it is!